Qwik Error - Cannot find module qwik-cli.js
I tried adding the TailwindCSS after initializing a fresh Qwik project, but I recieved an error with this content:
> qwik "add" "tailwind"

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PC-Master\Desktop\Projects\revonca-fe\revonca-fe\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\qwik-cli.cjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v21.6.0
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.


What seems to have fixed the issue is running pnpm install and then rerunning the command for adding the tailwind pnpm run qwik add tailwind
Weird thing is that when project was initialized, I was told by the CLI that it will install all the dependencies.
